# Html curl scraper to get gmaps info

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get an information of a page and the page has google maps. 
I'm retrieving the page with curl and I get all html except the divs of the map.
How can I get that information?

The page is:
https://www.groupon.com/deals/the-skydeck-at-willis-tower-184

So I need to get with curl the address content inside map.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this data, your browser send ajax request to url https://www.groupon.com/deals/merchant_locations_proxy/the-skydeck-at-willis-tower-184.json?get_user_geo_details=true&page_type=local

So you can use mask `https://www.groupon.com/deals/merchant_locations_proxy/<url unique part>.json?get_user_geo_details=true&page_type=local`